# which lucene package i should choose? there are so many packages when i search in nexus

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, lucene, nexus

is there any tutorial which can help me to choose between these packages?

[image: since there are too many choice, i don't know which one i should choose]

Comment: You probably want `lucene-core`. Install others as necessary.

Comment: @AdamEberlin what is the feature of other packages? how to know the functionality of them?

Comment: @AdamEberlin how to mark your comments as answer?

Comment: I reposted my comments as an answer. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `lucene-core`. Install others as necessary.

For the ones you are not familiar with, I would suggest using Google.

That's what everybody else does :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using it with java, I would use [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), which is a flavour of lucene that supports saving basic java types natively.

I've used it on several projects, always very successfully.

Comment: why solr? seems it is built on lucene?

Comment: yes, solr *is* lucene, but with add-ons to support read/write of java boxed primitives and a few other classes. if you're saving documents with java objects as values, solr is a good choice